# Ubuntu, using a shell script to loop a C program

Tags: linux, shell-script, c

I have a C program `./myProgram 1` (where 1 is the argument fixed) in the directory

```
gianni@mylinux:~/myWork/myApplication$ ./myProgram
```

I wish to run this C program 100 times using a loop insted a very not elegant solution to copy 100 times the line `gianni@mylinux:~/myWork/myApplication$ ./myProgram` in a shell script

Comment: Is the argument always `1`, or should that increment, or...?

Comment: not it's fixed. Just 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write on the command line:

```
i=0; while [ $((i+=1)) -le 100 ]; do ./myProgram 1; done
```

Assuming your IFS does not have numbers in it, or just quote as "$((i+=1))"

Or (with ksh, bash, zsh)

```
for i in {1..100}; do ./myProgram 1; done
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be easily accomplished using the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(seq 1 100); do
  ./myProgram 1
done
```

Or with a one-liner version:

`for i in $(seq 1 100); do ./myProgram 1; done`

Comment: There is the (small) chance that IFS could remove some numbers from the (unquoted) expansion of `seq`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `zsh` shell:

```
repeat 100 do ./myProgram 1; done
```

or

```
repeat 100 do
    ./myProgram 1
done
```

The `repeat` loop has the following generic form:

```
repeat word do list done
```

where `word` is expanded and treated as an arithmetic expression that tells the shell how many iterations to run, and where `list` is the list of commands that should be run in each iteration (a list of commands is always terminated by a command terminator, such as `;` or newline).

From `bash`:

```
zsh -c 'repeat 100 do ./myProgram 1; done'
```